# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to create an init.d file  to start node-red on startup. I'm using the following script, but keep getting the error "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string". I can't figure out which line is missing the quote.  I tried adding quote to "node-red, but it still doesn't work.  I'd appreciate any help.

```
#! /bin/sh
# Starts and stops Node-RED
# /etc/init.d/node_red
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     node_red
# Required-Start:       $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $syslog
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Node-RED initialisation
### END INIT INFO
# Note: this runs as the user called pi

PIDFILE=/var/run/nodered.pid

#Load up node red when called
case "$1" in

start)
        echo "Starting Node-Red.."
        su -l pi -c cd "node-red; screen -dmS red node --max-old-space-size=64 red.js
        echo `screen -ls red | sed -n '2p' | cut -f1 -d.` &gt; $PIDFILE
# or
        #nohup node --max-old-space-size=128 red.js &gt; /var/log/node-red.log &amp;
        #echo $! &gt; $PIDFILE
;;

stop)
        echo "Stopping Node-Red.."
        su -l pi -c "screen -S red -X quit"
# or
        #kill `cat $PIDFILE`
        rm -f $PIDFILE
;;

restart)
        echo "Restarting Node-Red.."
        $0 stop
        $0 start
;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```

Comment: See the `"node-red;` part?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment the problem is the line after `echo "Starting Node-Red.."`

You need move the opening " to before the cd and to add a closing " to the end of that line:

```
...
case "$1" in

start)
        echo "Starting Node-Red.."
        su -l pi -c "cd node-red; screen -dmS red node --max-old-space-size=64 red.js"
        echo `screen -ls red | sed -n '2p' | cut -f1 -d.` &gt; $PIDFILE
# or
        #nohup node --max-old-space-size=128 red.js > /var/log/node-red.log &amp;
        #echo $! &gt; $PIDFILE
;;
...
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!